# Remote server closed connection after 0 response bytes read

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I'm using VMware vCenter Converter standalone 4.3.0 to virtualize a windows 2003 server. The server has a 53 GB disk, after 4% the virtualization fails the error message:

```
Remote server closed connection after 0 response bytes read
```

UPDATE:

In the converter log I can see:

```
87.79.76.802012-10-04T15:17:11.140+02:00 [03860 verbose 'Ufa.HTTPService'] User agent is 'VMware-client/5.0.0'
2012-10-04T15:17:11.140+02:00 [03860 verbose 'Ufa.HTTPService'] HTTP Response: Auto-completing at 129/129 bytes
2012-10-04T15:17:11.140+02:00 [03860 verbose 'Ufa'] Responded to service state request
2012-10-04T15:17:36.968+02:00 [04044 error 'Default'] Unable to allocate memory: 414348496 bytes
2012-10-04T15:17:37.046+02:00 [04044 info 'Default'] CoreDump: Writing minidump
2012-10-04T15:17:38.453+02:00 [04044 panic 'Default'] 
--> 
--> Panic: Unable to allocate memory
--> Backtrace:
--> backtrace[00] rip 000008f4 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[01] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[02] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[03] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[04] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[05] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[06] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[07] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[08] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[09] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[10] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[11] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[12] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[13] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[14] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[15] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[16] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[17] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[18] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[19] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[20] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[21] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[22] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[23] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[24] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[25] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[26] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[27] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[28] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[29] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[30] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[31] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[32] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[33] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[34] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[35] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[36] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[37] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[38] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[39] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[40] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[41] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[42] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[43] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[44] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[45] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[46] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[47] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[48] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[49] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[50] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[51] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[52] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[53] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[54] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[55] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[56] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[57] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[58] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[59] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[60] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> backtrace[61] rip 00000000 (no symbol)
--> 
2012-10-04T15:17:38.453+02:00 [04044 panic 'Default'] (Log recursion level 2) Unable to allocate memory
------ In-memory logs end   --------
2012-10-04T15:17:38.453+02:00 [04044 panic 'Default'] Section for VMware vCenter Converter Standalone, pid=944, version=5.0.0, build=build-470252, option=Release
-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in the vmware Knowledge Base:

[Converting a virtual machine using VMware vCenter Converter fails with the error: Unable to allocate memory error](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031065)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the remote server killed the connection...

Really, this setup probably looks like you installed vCenter Converter on the Windows 2003 server and pointed it to a target location of... a vCenter or standalone ESXi host? Make sure you have as little as possible between the two (firewalls, etc.) and try again. The converter utility should also have some detailed logs...

Comment: I've updated the question, the reason seems to be a out of memory exception ...